# Assert unique key constraint on h2 database with slick and scalatest

Tags: scala, tdd, h2, slick, scalatest

Imagine the following scenario: You have a book that consists of ordered chapters.

First the **test**:

```
"Chapters" should "have a unique order" in
{
    //  val exception = intercept
    db.run(
      DBIO.seq
      (
        Chapters.add(0, 0, "Chapter #0"),
        Chapters.add(0, 0, "Chapter #1")
      )
    )
}
```

Now the **implementation**:

```
case class Chapter(id: Option[Long] = None, bookId: Long, order: Long, val title: String) extends Model

class Chapters(tag: Tag) extends Table[Chapter](tag, "chapters")
{
  def id = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def bookId = column[Long]("book_id")
  def order = column[Long]("order")
  def title = column[String]("title")

  def * = (id, bookId, order, title) <> (Chapter.tupled, Chapter.unapply)
  def uniqueOrder = index("order_chapters", (bookId, order), unique = true)

  def bookFK = foreignKey("book_fk", bookId, Books.all)(_.id.get, onUpdate = ForeignKeyAction.Cascade, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.Restrict)
}
```

Maybe such a unique-constraint on 2 columns isn't even possible in `h2`?

Anyway:

**Expectation:**
An exception to be thrown that I can then intercept/expect in my test, hence a failing test for now, for violating a unique-constraint.

**Actual result:**
A successful test :(

**edit**: Also, I use this:

`implicit val defaultPatience =
    PatienceConfig(timeout = Span(30, Seconds), interval = Span(100, Millis))`

Comment: Can't you see the generated schema? Check the table definition inside h2 itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.run` returns a `Future`. 
You have to `Await` on it to get the result of the execution.
Try this:

```
 import scala.concurrent.duration._
 val future = db.run(...)
 Await.result(future, 5 seconds)
```

Comment: I probably should've mentioned this: `implicit val defaultPatience =
    PatienceConfig(timeout = Span(30, Seconds), interval = Span(100, Millis))`

Comment: I don't see how it matters for anything

Comment: I never used await in my tests and always a default patience. http://www.artima.com/docs-scalatest-2.0.M5/org/scalatest/concurrent/PatienceConfiguration.html

Comment: You don't need await as long as you are not expecting an exception of want to examine the returned object synchronously (i.e., not inside `.map` or `.onSuccess` etc.)

Comment: That was what I was missing, thank you. I'll test asap